# Set RTF text into WPF RichTextBox control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, richtextbox

I have this RTF text:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Arial;}}
{\colortbl ;\red0\green0\blue0;\red255\green0\blue0;}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\qc\cf1\fs16 test \b bold \cf2\b0\i italic\cf0\i0\fs17 
\par }
```

How to set this text into [WPF RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.aspx)?

---

Solution:

```
public void SetRTFText(string text)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(text));
    this.mainRTB.Selection.Load(stream, DataFormats.Rtf);
}
```

Comment: Just 1 remark, are you sure you want ASCII encoding? It could be but UTF8 or default usually make more sense.

Comment: Yes, in case that I have, ASCII Encoding is what I need to use. Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: Actually, you're **not** using ASCII encoding with this code... `Default` actually refers to `Encoding.Default`, so it's the system's default ANSI codepage. Beware of accessing static members through derived classes, it is often misleading.

Comment: This technique works, but I get an error if the text parameter is an empty string. If this is a possible case, then you might need to add a special handling.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Do you really have to start with a string?

One method to load RTF is this:

```
rtfBox.Selection.Load(myStream, DataFormats.Rtf);
```

You probably should call SelectAll() before that if you want to replace existing text.

So, worst case, you'll have to write your string to a MemoryStream and then feed that stream to the Load() method. Don't forget to Position=0 in between.

But I'm waiting to see somebody to come up with something more elegant.

Comment: rtfBox.Selection.Load is what I needed. Thank you :)

Comment: Instead of using the `Selection` property and worrying about calling SelectAll, you can probably use `new TextRange( rtfBox.Document.ContentStart, rtfBox.Document.ContentEnd )` and then call Load on the TextRange (Selection is itself a TextRange).

Comment: with devios's snippet, this works: `TextRange textRange = new TextRange( rtfBox.Document.ContentStart, rtfBox.Document.ContentEnd ); MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream( ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes( rtfText ) ); textRange.Load( ms, DataFormats.Rtf );`

Answer (score 9):

Create an Extension method

```
    public static void SetRtf(this RichTextBox rtb, string document)
    {
        var documentBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(document);
        using (var reader = new MemoryStream(documentBytes))
        {
            reader.Position = 0;
            rtb.SelectAll();
            rtb.Selection.Load(reader, DataFormats.Rtf);
        }
    }
```

Then you can do WinForm-esque style

`richTextBox1.SetRtf(rtf);`

Comment: You can't use extension method as property.

Answer (score -2):

```
string rtf = @"{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Arial;}} {\colortbl ;\red0\green0\blue0;\red255\green0\blue0;} \viewkind4\uc1\pard\qc\cf1\fs16 test \b bold \cf2\b0\i italic\cf0\i0\fs17  \par } ";
richTextBox1.Rtf = rtf;
```

It's working fine

Comment: That's for Windows Forms, the question specifies WPF.

Answer (score -3):

**Edit**: This answer assumes WinForms instead of WPF.

Simply use RichTextBox.Rtf:

```
string rtf = @"{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Arial;}} {\colortbl ;\red0\green0\blue0;\red255\green0\blue0;} \viewkind4\uc1\pard\qc\cf1\fs16 test \b bold \cf2\b0\i italic\cf0\i0\fs17  \par } ";
richTextBox1.Rtf = rtf;
```

Comment: Oh my bad. I missed you where using WPF.